# Subgroups of Galois group and intermediate fields lattice for $(x^3-2)(x^2-3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to systematically determine all subgroups of Galois group  and intermediate fields for $(x^3-2)(x^2-3)$(over $\mathbb Q$).

It's not hard to determine the Galois group of $(x^3-2)$ and $(x^2-3)$ separately. However, I don't know how to determine the Galois group of $(x^3-2)(x^2-3)$. Is there a powerful theorem telling us the relation between the Galois group of a **reducible** polynomial and the Galois groups of its **irreducible factors**?

Moreover, I don't know the general method for such a problem. Hungerford drew some lattices for subgroups and intermediate fields in his book without verification. I am wondering how to determine **all** of the subgroups and their relations.

Every detailed solution for this specific problem will be appreciated!

Comment: http://planetmath.org/galoisgroupofthecompositumoftwogaloisextensions

Comment: I believe that page has the idea you need.  In other words when a Galois group is a direct product.

Answer (score -1):

*"Is there a powerful theorem telling us the relation between the Galois group of a reducible polynomial and the Galois groups of its irreducible factors?"*

You might be looking for [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).
In your case one finds the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{108})/\mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{108})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{108})$ (one can check that $\frac{1}{6}\left( \sqrt[6]{108}\right)^{3} = \sqrt{3}$ and $\frac{1}{18}\left( \sqrt[6]{108}\right)^{4} = \sqrt[3]{2}$). In this way, your question about the "reducible polynomial" leads back to the "irreducible polynomial" and we are back in familiar territory.